# Windows 7 flashing 'No internet access' icon in tray every few seconds when using VPN and directly connected to cable modem

Tags: vpn, modem

My Windows 7 machine is connected directly to my cable modem. When i am not using VPN, the connection is stable. When using VPN, however, the icon indicating an ethernet cord connection in the tray gets a yellow exclamation (which means 'No internet access') every few seconds, then it goes away. The VPN connection remains stable, but I'm wondering why this is happening? I have an Arris.

Perhaps related: When I connect this computer to my wireless router instead of directly to the modem, eventually the VPN causes the wireless router to disconnect all connected users, closing the VPN. I have a thread on that [here](https://superuser.com/questions/222459/wireless-router-disconnecting-when-using-vpn). However, I have not been disconnected yet being connected directly to the modem. Anyone know what the issue might be here?